# MS Access - You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified ... as part of an aggregate function

Tags: sql, ms-access

My aggregate function is giving me this error in Microsoft Access 2010. This is the query in question:

```
SELECT
    curr.FileDate, curr.ProdNr, 
    Count(curr.ProdNr) as CountOfProdNr, 
    curr.Desc, 
    IIf(prev.ProdNr is Null, IIf(curr.Status="1", "NEW", "ERR"), 
    IIf(curr.Status<>prev.Status, 
    Switch(
    curr.Status="7", "CAN", 
    curr.Status="T", "TRM", 
    True, "OTH"), 
    IIf(curr.Status="1", "REG", "HIS"))) as Transaction, 
    curr.Status, 
    prev.Status as PrevStatus, 
    min(curr.StartDate) as MinOfStartDate, 
    max(curr.EndDate) as MaxOfEndDate, 
    curr.CancelCode, 
    max(curr.OrigAmt) as MaxOfOrigAmt,
    Switch(curr.Desc="ML", IIf(MaxOfOrigAmt>500000, 500000, MaxOfOrigAmt), 
    curr.Desc="MC", IIf(MaxOfOrigAmt>300000, 300000, MaxOfOrigAmt), 
    True, MaxOfOrigAmt) as Cap, 
    Switch(prev.Desc="ML", IIf(max(prev.OrigAmt)>500000, 500000, max(prev.OrigAmt)), 
    prev.Desc="MC", IIf(max(prev.OrigAmt)>300000, 300000, max(prev.OrigAmt)), 
    True, max(prev.OrigAmt)) as PrevCap, 
    Switch(curr.Desc="ML", IIf(max(curr.Balance)>500000, 500000, max(curr.Balance)), 
    curr.Desc="MC", IIf(max(curr.Balance)>300000, 300000, max(curr.Balance)), 
    True, max(curr.Balance)) as BalCap, 
    Switch(prev.Desc="ML", IIf(max(prev.Balance)>500000, 500000, max(prev.Balance)), 
    prev.Desc="MC", IIf(max(prev.Balance)>300000, 300000, max(prev.Balance)), 
    prev.Desc Is Null, 0, 
    True, max(prev.Balance)) as PrevBalCap, 
    CDbl(BalCap-PrevBalCap) as BalCapChange, 
    curr.JointIndicator, curr.OrigAmt, 
    max(curr.Balance)-Nz(max(prev.Balance), 0) as BalanceChange
FROM 
    Cov as curr 
    LEFT JOIN Cov_PREVMONTH as prev 
    ON curr.Ref = prev.Ref
GROUP BY
    curr.FileDate, 
    curr.Desc, 
    curr.ProdNr, 
    curr.Status, 
    prev.Status, 
    IIf(prev.ProdNr is Null, IIf(curr.Status="1", "NEW", "ERR"), 
    IIf(curr.Status<>prev.Status, 
    Switch(
    curr.Status="7", "CAN", 
    curr.Status="T", "TRM", 
    True, "OTH"), 
    IIf(curr.Status="1", "REG", "HIS"))),
    curr.CancelCode, 
    curr.JointIndicator, 
    curr.OrigAmt
```

Pardon my terrible coding. The error comes for this expression:

```
Switch(prev.Desc="ML", IIf(max(prev.OrigAmt)>500000, 500000, max(prev.OrigAmt)), 
prev.Desc="MC", IIf(max(prev.OrigAmt)>300000, 300000, max(prev.OrigAmt)), 
True, max(prev.OrigAmt))
```

When I try to get around the error and put this expression under the `GROUP BY` clause, I get the error

> Cannot have aggregate function in GROUP BY clause

I am out of ideas - what's wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question and how the entire query.

Comment: That's not your "query in question". That's an out-of-context excerpt from your query, as is the `FROM` clause you've included. Please post the actual query that is causing the problem. If you're not sure why this is needed, go to your auto mechanic and say "My car isn't working right. It's a Ford, and it sounds just like the one that drove by about 2 minutes ago. What's wrong, and how much will it cost to fix?" and see if you get an estimate.

Comment: All I can say with certainty without seeing more of the query is that `prev.Desc` needs to be included in the `GROUP BY`, along with any other columns you are not including in an aggregate function

Comment: I've added the full query. But it seems GarethD hit it - prev.Desc it is. Thank you!